# How do I reduce the number of GPIO pins used for a CMOS camera?

Tags: gpio, pins, camera

I'm gonna make a cheap 360 camera with 5 of these [OV7670 cameras](https://www.amazon.ca/CMOS-OV7670-Camera-Module-Quality/dp/B008D8PMA4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1463830671&sr=8-1&keywords=ov7670) but they use a whopping 18 GPIO pins each! (Btw, 18 X 5 = 90 Pins!) I'm using a C.H.I.P computer to control all this mess, but even then, it only has 80 GPIO pins! I've seen a camera that only uses four pins and the only reason I'm buying this is because it's dirt cheap. Is there any way to shorten the amount of pins this camera uses?

Comment: Taking a look at http://www.arducam.com/camera-modules/0-3mp-ov7670/ and http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/07/hacking-ov7670-camera-module-sccb-cheat.html , I don't think the OV7670 will do the job. The lack of on-camera buffering will make it nearly impossible to synchronize five cameras.

Comment: I can see 3v3, 5v and gnd, so that's three power pins that don't need to go to gpio, the two I2C (or sscb or whatever) pins from each camera could be multiplexed with one of those I2C bus multiplexers (I've seen up to 8 ch), one of the pins is probably the input clock and can be shared between all the cameras. The main data lines are going to be the 8 colour pins, pixel clock, frame clock, vertical sync and horizontal sync. But that's an awful lot of data (20+ MHz pixel clock * 8bits/pixel*5 cameras = at least 800 megabits a second - probably more, can your micro handle that?)

Comment: @Tom Yes it can, my "microcontroller" is actually a 9$ computer with 512mb of ram!

Comment: That doesn't automatically mean it can do anything other than write the raw data to memory (no real post processing or encoding), ironically, using a full blown computer may make it *slower* as you don't quite have the same low level (i.e. high speed) gpio access as you would've had in an embedded system. If it's a full computer, it may be easier to use USB webcams. USB is much better equipped to handle bulk data transfers than GPIO if you're running from inside an OS, *BUT*, don't let that stop you from trying it anyway, give it a go, see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Going by the pinout described [here](http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/07/hacking-ov7670-camera-module-sccb-cheat.html), you would need 5x 8-data lines, 2 config lines for each camera. The clock and synchronization signals (4), plus the power/reset signals (2) could be common to all of the devices. This would give 56 total signals required, plus power/ground to each of the devices.

However, I'm not sure you can receive all 5 sets of data correctly from the devices using GPIO pins.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't bothered to link a datasheet or pinout, but I don't see how they use 24 GPIO pins.

For a start, that's an 18 pin connector, and the camera probably uses two pins for power, so at most that's 16 pins per camera.

Second, there's probably a way to avoid connecting all five pins simultaneously: you can probably get away with a mux for various pins, and there's probably a chip select or similar so that you can tie multiple drive pins together.

You're going to have very low refresh rate, but you'll probably be limited by the C.H.I.P.'s GPIO bandwidth anyway, so hopefully you're already OK with that.

Finally, the Google suggests that the camera uses an 8bit parallel interface, so if you're still short on GPIO pins, you could use a shift register to serialize that port. Deserializing on the other end is left as an exercise to the reader.